# Does there exist an infinite amount of prime numbers with its binary representarion being prime in base 10?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binary

I'll try and explain what I asked. Take the number $5$, which is prime. Its binary representation, $101$, is also prime. I computed a program in python that picks all numbers from a list that verifies this ($k$ is prime and its binary representation is prime if we consider it as a decimal representation), and it keeps showing numbers up until $5000$ (which is as far as I checked).

I guess we first had to prove that there exists an infinite amount of primes numbers whose digits are onle $0's$ and $1's$, and then we would have to prove that the number of prime numbers (let's call the set of primes $A$) is the same as the number of prime numbers with digits $0's$ and $1's$ (let's call this set $B$). This second part can be easy ifthe first result is true, since $B\subset A \subset \Bbb N$. So the second result is true.

Does anyone have any idea on how to prove the first result? Or anything similar to it? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks to Peter and CyclotomicField for some insight! I run a program in python that showed how many primes of this type can be found from $2$ to $1001$, $1002$ to $2001$, $2002$ to $3001$, ... until $1000001$. I drew in Mathematica the list of these numbers of primes, and got this:
[image]

It might not be much, but I thought it was interesting...

Comment: We don't know that much about anti-Yarborough primes but you can find more of them here. https://oeis.org/A020449

Comment: Oh, so they have a name! I didn't know it was an open question... At least we can assure that the second result is true. We would only need the first one to be true, right?

Comment: 1. It is very likely that there are infinite many prime numbers with only digits $0$ and $1$ in its decimal expansion, but I highly doubt that this is proven. 2. Would you be content with very large examples of prime numbers as desired (say several hundred digits) ?

Comment: 3. My guess is that there are infinite many primes as desired , but a proof will be out of reach.

Comment: I didn't know they had a name till today either but I'm curious about questions involving string conversion and a change of base. They typically prove to be hard but if we could say more about them I think number theory would find a use for it.

Comment: A large example is $$p=10^{500}+641041$$ The prime has $501$ digits and the corresponding binary string $1\ 661$ digits.

Comment: @Peter how did you get that prime? But sadly no, that example doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @GreekCorpse Of course not, but in such cases we are usually utterly helpless anyway concerning a proof. I found the prime just by brute force beginning with $10^{500}$

Comment: @CyclotomicField I got the inspiration from a twitter bot that showcases all primes. Last week, one of those prime numbers was the binary equivalent of 89, which is also prime. It felt interesting, and wanted to see more. Who knows what uses it can have...

Comment: @Peter True... But wow, by brute force? You must have a supercomputer to do so.

Comment: @GreekCorpse Not really, PARI/GP with a usual computer (not even the newest) is enough. Of course I sieved out small prime factors of both the number and the binary expansion to accelerate the search.

Comment: @Peter I'm still forced to marvel at the advancements we've made in discovering primes. Imagine what Euler would have done with it.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Indeed, he should have lived in our time ! He would surely also be fascinated of the prime generating polynomial with 26 variables.

Comment: Just in the case someone is interested , an even larger example is $$10^{1000}+11413591$$

Comment: @Peter is it ok if you share the code for either of the programs you've used? I'm interested on how you did it.

Comment: @GreekCorpse I found the example by letting run three programs simultaneously with different ranges for the random number $s$ in $10^{1000}+s$. I can reprogram and post the routine for the brute force search, but I am not sure how efficient it is. If you are interested, I can post it in such a way that the exponent can be modified.

Comment: Sure, that would be awesome!

Comment: This is the PARI/GP-code (the exponent is $k$ , since trial division is involved , it should be at least $7$) : k=50;s=10^k;z=prod(j=1,3*10^4,prime(j));gef=0;while(gef==0,s=s+1;t=fromdigits(digits(s,2));if(gcd(z,s*t)==1,if(ispseudoprime(s)==1,print(s-10^k);if(ispseudoprime(t)==1,gef=1))))

Comment: If the program terminates , the last output , let us call it $s$ , gives the desired number , namely $10^k+s$.

Comment: The primalities of the number and its binary partner are not proven, but the extremely reliable BPSW-test is used (no counterexample is known!). If you insist on primality proving , you can replace "ispseusoprime(s)" by "isprime(s,2)" and analogur for t , but this slows down the routine significantly for large k , in particular for $k\ge 1\ 000$

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing it!